# android database shows no column defined

Tags: android, sqlite

In android code I declared all column names correctly.But still on running it shows error that column is missing.In android code I declared all column names correctly.But still on running it shows error that column is missing

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_STAT = "stat";
    private static final String KEY_PACK = "pack";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

// Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE, "
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_STAT + "TEXT,"
                + KEY_PACK + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }
```

adduser()

```
public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String stat, String pack) {
        //public void addUser(String name, String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_STAT, stat); // Created At
        values.put(KEY_PACK, pack);
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

logcat

```
03-05 07:14:42.579: E/SQLiteLog(1454): (1) table login has no column named stat
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454): Error inserting uid=7 pack=3 email=shank15@hotmail.com stat=1 name=Shashank
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table login has no column named stat (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO login(uid,pack,email,stat,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
03-05 07:14:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(1454):     at com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler.addUser(DatabaseHandler.java:77)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add missing space between column name and type. Change

```
+ KEY_STAT + "TEXT,"
```

to

```
+ KEY_STAT + " TEXT,"
```

After modifying `onCreate()`, uninstall your app so the database gets recreated. See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run) for more.

Comment: @SimplePlan, Its 5th column, watch carefully, You need eagle eye :)

Comment: Updated the answer to make the change more obvious.

Comment: @Kedarnath you are right.  it's Refresh problem.sorry guys!

Comment: @SimplePlan to catch such mistake your eyes needs to be free from [Computer Vision Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision_syndrome)